# Leaflet image overlay align with pixel coordinates on map

Tags: leaflet, overlay, pix4d

I have successfully displayed my image on a map at specific location using the bounds of a polygon. Here is the screenshot of the image displayed on top of map at around specific boundary bounds.

[image]

```
var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(this.imageUrl, this.projectBoundary.getBounds(), {
      opacity: 0.8,
      interactive: true
      }).addTo(this.map);

    var draggableOverlay = new L.Draggable(imageOverlay._image);
      draggableOverlay.enable();
```

I am able to drag it as well and change the location of the image. But what I am trying to achieve is something like in below screenshot, where I can specify specific pixel a coordinate (bounds) values, and then corners would be inside that.

Basically, I have two pixel points selected on my image, and now I want to align those point pixel with the bounds of the boundary on the map, just like in the below screenshot, you can see that there are two x icons, one is top left and one is at bottom, they are at specific pixel value of the image.

How can I do that in Leaflet image overlay? And then I want to use those two point to resize the image as well on the map. How can I do that in Leaflet? I haven't been able to find the solution for this.

[image]

This is something that pix4d is doing when you upload image Design, and I want to implement something like that in my application.

I have tried these plugins, but they don't let me provide corners at specific pixel

https://github.com/publiclab/Leaflet.DistortableImage

**Edited:**

Explaining again that, I can mark two points on my image by first viewing the image and click on the image to get two pixel values, upper left, and lower right, and I have the bound (upper left, and lower right) from the polygon, now I want to align the image and polygon bounds in a way that the two points of image should be at polygon's bounds, not the corners of the image, just like attached in the second screenshot.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean by "I want to align those point pixel with the bounds of the boundary on the map". How can you align two pixel points with with some boundary? What shape is this boundary? To what points of this boundary you want to align those two pixels? Please edit you question and explain this more in detail.

Comment: So, what i mean is that, i will mark two points on my image, upper left and lower right, and then i have the bound (upper left, lower right ) of the polygon as well, i want to align that in a way that those points (pixel) on my image should be at the bounds of the polygon.

Comment: I have edited to add more details, i hope it explains.

Comment: It explains a bit more, but what is missing is explanation of "I will mark two points on my image". How is this marking going to happen? By clicking on image? Or some other way? Please add also that info.

Comment: First that image windows opens, user mark two points on the image by click, i get the clicked pixel values, and then on next step it goes to map .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below is more a proof of concept than a bulletproof solution and is based upon the following suppositions:

- image has the same CRS as map;
- image is not rotated;
- image/map is shown at high zoom so that cartesian math can be used when doing coordinates calculations.

Coordinates calculations are done the following way:

- geographic coordinates are converted to map container pixel coordinates using Leaflet map `.latLngToContainerPoint` method;
- calculations are the done with pixel coordinates using Leaflet point methods `.subtract`, `.add` and `.scaleBy`.
- pixel coordinates are converted back to gegographic coordinates using Leaflet map `.containerPointToLatLng` method.

Logic of showing the image and the aligning it with polygon boundary box with the help of two reference points:

- first image is loaded to image object so that image width and height are obtained;
- then image is add the the map is image overlay, with the size adapted to polygon bounding box, but slightly bigger;
- image overlay is implemented so that image is draggable;
- first click on image creates first reference point (upper left), second click creates second reference point (lower right);
- on reference points markers are created that can be moved after creation; if image is moved, markers move with it;
- after two reference points are created, Shift/click on image triggers image alignment with polygon bounding box (image resize and move);
- even after that image (together with markers) can still be dragged around, markers moved and image alignment can be triggered.

This is the whole code:

```
var polygon = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              14.498654936369007,
              46.051729567644514
            ],
            [
              14.497747328622921,
              46.049827987411476
            ],
            [
              14.50002491032447,
              46.04924561536964
            ],
            [
              14.50216549463181,
              46.04899602547175
            ],
            [
              14.502970354330415,
              46.05076690083402
            ],
            [
              14.500966767419357,
              46.05147998897175
            ],
            [
              14.498654936369007,
              46.051729567644514
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
};

var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 20
});

var polygonLayer = L.geoJSON(polygon, {
  interactive: false
});
var polygonBounds = polygonLayer.getBounds();
var polygonBoundsRectangle = L.rectangle(polygonBounds, {
  fill: false,
  interactive: false
});
var polygonBoundsLayer = L.featureGroup([polygonBoundsRectangle]);

var map = L.map('map', {
 layers: [baseLayer, polygonLayer, polygonBoundsLayer]
}).setView([46.05, 14.5], 17);

 
function adjustByFactor(pixelCoords, pixelOrigin, factorH, factorV) {
  var pixelCoordsFromOrigin = pixelCoords.subtract(pixelOrigin);
  pixelCoordsFromOrigin = pixelCoordsFromOrigin.scaleBy(L.point([factorH, factorV]));
  
  return(pixelCoordsFromOrigin.add(pixelOrigin));
}
  

function loadImageOverlay(imgWidth, imgHeight) {
  var boundsCornerPixels1 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(polygonLayer.getBounds().getNorthWest());
  var boundsCornerPixels2 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(polygonLayer.getBounds().getSouthEast());
  
  var boundsCenterPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(polygonLayer.getBounds().getCenter())
  var imageHeightPixels = Math.abs(boundsCornerPixels2.y - boundsCornerPixels1.y);
  var imageWidthPixels = imageHeightPixels * (imgWidth / imgHeight);
  var imageCornerPixels1 = boundsCenterPixels.subtract(L.point([imageWidthPixels / 2, imageHeightPixels / 2]));
  var imageCornerPixels2 = boundsCenterPixels.add(L.point([imageWidthPixels / 2, imageHeightPixels / 2]));
  var imageCorner1 = map.containerPointToLatLng(imageCornerPixels1);
  var imageCorner2 = map.containerPointToLatLng(imageCornerPixels2);

  var imageBounds = L.latLngBounds(imageCorner1, imageCorner2).pad(0.15);
  var imageLayer = L.imageOverlay('img/image-for-layer.png', imageBounds, {
    interactive: true,
    opacity: 0.7
  });
  imageLayer.addTo(map);
  
  var draggable = new L.Draggable(imageLayer.getElement());
  draggable.enable();
  
  var markers = [];
  var wasDrag = false;
  var prevDragPosition;
  draggable.on('dragstart drag dragend', function(evt) {
    wasDrag = true;
    if (evt.type == 'dragstart')
      prevDragPosition = evt.target._startPos;
    else if (evt.type == 'dragend') {
      var move = evt.target._newPos.subtract(evt.target._startPos);
      var bounds = imageLayer.getBounds();
      var boundsNW = bounds.getNorthWest();
      var boundsSE = bounds.getSouthEast();
      var boundsNWPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(boundsNW);
      var boundsSEPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(boundsSE);
      var newBoundsNWPixels = boundsNWPixels.add(move);
      var newBoundsSEPixels = boundsSEPixels.add(move);
      var newBoundsNW = map.containerPointToLatLng(newBoundsNWPixels);
      var newBoundsSE = map.containerPointToLatLng(newBoundsSEPixels);
      imageLayer.setBounds(L.latLngBounds(newBoundsNW, newBoundsSE));
      }
    else {
      var move = evt.target._newPos.subtract(prevDragPosition);
      prevDragPosition = evt.target._newPos;
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        var markerPixel = map.latLngToContainerPoint(marker.getLatLng());
        var newMarkerPixel = markerPixel.add(move);
        marker.setLatLng(map.containerPointToLatLng(newMarkerPixel));
      });
    }
  });
  
  imageLayer.on('click', function(evt) {
    if (wasDrag)
      wasDrag = false;
    else if (markers.length < 2) {
      var marker = L.marker(evt.latlng, {draggable: true}).addTo(map);
      markers.push(marker);
      }
    else if (evt.originalEvent.shiftKey) {
      var marker1LatLng = markers[0].getLatLng();
      var marker1Pixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(marker1LatLng);
      var marker2LatLng = markers[1].getLatLng();
      var marker2Pixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(marker2LatLng);
      var markersDistPixelsH = Math.abs(marker1Pixels.x - marker2Pixels.x);
      var markersDistPixelsV = Math.abs(marker1Pixels.y - marker2Pixels.y);       
      var polygonBoundsNW = polygonBounds.getNorthWest();
      var polygonBoundsNWPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(polygonBoundsNW);
      var polygonBoundsSE = polygonBounds.getSouthEast();
      var polygonBoundsSEPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(polygonBoundsSE);
      var polygonBoundsDistPixelsH = Math.abs(polygonBoundsNWPixels.x - polygonBoundsSEPixels.x);
      var polygonBoundsDistPixelsV = Math.abs(polygonBoundsNWPixels.y - polygonBoundsSEPixels.y);
      var factorH = polygonBoundsDistPixelsH / markersDistPixelsH;
      var factorV = polygonBoundsDistPixelsV / markersDistPixelsV;

      var bounds = imageLayer.getBounds();
      var boundsNW = bounds.getNorthWest();
      var boundsSE = bounds.getSouthEast();
      var boundsNWPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(boundsNW);
      var boundsSEPixels = map.latLngToContainerPoint(boundsSE);
      var boundsSEPixels = adjustByFactor(boundsSEPixels, boundsNWPixels, factorH, factorV);
      var marker1Pixels = adjustByFactor(marker1Pixels, boundsNWPixels, factorH, factorV);
      var marker2Pixels = adjustByFactor(marker2Pixels, boundsNWPixels, factorH, factorV);

      var move = polygonBoundsNWPixels.subtract(marker1Pixels);

      var newBoundsNWPixels = boundsNWPixels.add(move);
      var newBoundsSEPixels = boundsSEPixels.add(move);
      var newBoundsNW = map.containerPointToLatLng(newBoundsNWPixels);
      var newBoundsSE = map.containerPointToLatLng(newBoundsSEPixels);
      imageLayer.setBounds(L.latLngBounds(newBoundsNW, newBoundsSE));

      var newMarker1Pixels = marker1Pixels.add(move);
      var newMarker2Pixels = marker2Pixels.add(move);
      var newMarker1LatLng =  map.containerPointToLatLng(newMarker1Pixels);
      var newMarker2LatLng =  map.containerPointToLatLng(newMarker2Pixels);
      markers[0].setLatLng(newMarker1LatLng);
      markers[1].setLatLng(newMarker2LatLng);
    }
  });
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  loadImageOverlay(img.width, img.height);
};
img.src = 'img/image-for-layer.png';
```

Example of polygon and image before alignment:

[image]

Polygon and image after reference points are created. During reference point creation image was dragged out of the way so that reference point on map were clearly visible:

[image]

Polygon and image after alignment:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for solution! It helped me resolved the issue.